# How to resolve the below error while running a c program to connect to Ms SQL server from Linux fedora7 using mssqlodbc

Tags: c, glibc, database-connectivity, msodbcsql17

How to resolve the below error while running a c program to connect to Ms SQL server from Linux fedora7 using mssqlodbc

Need to connect to Ms SQL server from c app on Linux fedora7 using msqlodbc

```
gcc -o prog prog.c -lc -lpthread -lodbcinst -lodbc -lm

/lib64/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__h_errno@GLIBC_PRIVATE'

lib64/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__mktemp@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
```

tried checking dependencies of libODBC using ldd and libc.so.6 is being pointed and also checked whether these symbols are present in libc.so.6 using nm -gdf libc.so.6. both the symbols are present in libc.so.6. still getting Undefined reference error.

Comment: That is weird.  Is there another libc on the system?  You shouldn't have to specify `-lc` or `-lm`.  Try without those and see if there is a difference.  Also, trying to access MS SQL server from Linux... Have you heard of `sqsh`?

Comment: Only one libc.so.6 is available. I got same error even after compiling without -lc,-lm. Able to connect  to Ms SQL server thru sqlcmd..

Comment: Odd.  So we are linking to the correct (only) libc and the symbols exist.  This might be an issue with linking order then.  Generally, you want to put the library that requires symbols *before* the library that has the symbols.  Try building like this `gcc -o prog prog.c  -lodbcinst -lodbc -lpthread -lm -lc`.  See if that works, or at the very least, gives you a different error.

Comment: I just looked at a project of mine and I used `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`.  That actually might have something to do with the errors too. So I think the command should be `gcc -o prog prog.c -pthread -lodbcinst -lodbc -lm -lc`.  I put it before the links because, for me, I used it as part of CFLAGS.

Comment: Tried the same way as you mentioned d. Still getting same errors.. __h_errno, __mktemp..

Comment: Wow... I'm kind of at a loss.  I feel like this has to be something incredibly odd on your system, and I would need access to poke and prod at it to give you a good answer.  It's not uncommon to have libraries get out of sync from incorrect usage of the package manager.  But I don't see how that can happen to pthread and libc.  Not only that, but you have poked the library yourself and saw that the symbol *are* present.  Nevertheless, all I have is a shot in the dark.  Try updating your system.  If your libraries are out of sync, that would fix it.